# C: ether_aton does not work

Tags: c, ethernet

I have the following function:

```
int parse_mac(const char *hwaddr, uint8_t *dst_mac)
{
    (void)hwaddr; (void)dst_mac;

    //TODO: Parse the MAC address (string) pointed to by hwaddr and store
    //the result in dst. Return 0 on success and -1 on error.

    struct ether_addr* ether_address = ether_aton(hwaddr);
    if(ether_address==NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        //*(dst_mac+i) = (*ether_address).ether_addr_octet[i];
    }
    printf("%c\n",(*ether_address).ether_addr_octet[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Given a MAC address (pointed to by hwaddr), I want to convert that into my `dst_mac` variable through `ether_aton`. However, The array inside the `ether_address` result struct is empty or so it seems. For example, the printf at the bottom gives me an empty char. What's wrong?

Comment: Print the octets as hex or decimal digits to see what the values are.  do not depend on the octet being a printable character.

Comment: Remove the first line of code. It is potentially dangerous.

Comment: Hi Richard Chambers, I printed the results as decimals: I get 0, 22, 62, 95, 2 and 31 in the array that is of size 6. How can I interpret those numbers?

Comment: As @Olaf said, why are you doing this: `(void)hwaddr; (void)dst_mac;`

Comment: To avoid compiler warnings

Comment: What is your input to this function? "00:16:3e:5f:02:1f"?

Comment: Yes, that is my input

Comment: Why are you using so weird pointer arithmetics and not just simply array access e.g.`dst_mac[i] = ether_address->ether_addr_octet[i]`?

Comment: So the `ether_aton` is working correctly. You just misinterpret the results. Mac address has hexadecimal values separated by ":". If you print your numbers as hexadecimal as proposed by @RichardChambers, you will get exactly the same numbers as in your mac address. try `printf("%02x ", ether_address->ether_addr_octet[i])` in the loop.

Comment: There is a good reason the compiler warns about unused arguments. Only use such dummy statements if you intend not to use a paramter intentionally. And then **always** leave a comment with that statement. There will be no warning for `hwaddr`, as that is used. **Instantly** remove such dummy-expressions if you use/intend to use a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, ether_aton converts your MAC Address, which has hexadecimal characters separated by colons to numbers. In my code, I am trying to print %c, when I should be printing %d.